# How can I get nested results from a MySQL table AND link to another table?

Tags: php, mysql

I have a table of comments:

---

comment_id  int(11)         No      auto_increment
profile_id  int(11)         No
type    char(1) latin1_swedish_ci       No
parent_id   int(11)         No
text    mediumtext  latin1_swedish_ci       No
datetime    datetime            No
vote_score  int(11)

---

Where "type" can be "a", a comment on an article, or "c", a comment on a comment (a reply)

"parent_id" says whether the comment is a child of article_id=1 or comment_id=1

It's linked to table "profiles" where comments.profile_id=profile.profile_id (so i can get profile.first_name, for example)

---

THE CHALLENGE:

I'd like to get a SQL query that gives me the comments in order as they'd be displayed:

> comment 1 [type=a]
>
> > (reply to comment 1) [type=c]
> >
> > (reply to comment 2)  [type=c]
>
> comment 2 [type=a]

What SQL query do I need to do this? (The objective is to return the results in correct order so I can have a SIMPLE php WHILE loop print the results.)

Thanks!

Comment: Is there only ever one level of the tree (only parents can have children), or can there be multiple (children can have children as well)?

Comment: update: Multiple levels. Children CAN have childrens. Thanks IRCmaxell

Comment: See, for example, the comments here: http://www.ted.com/talks/benjamin_zander_on_music_and_passion.html

Answer (score 1):

I think you might be interested in reading this article about [managing Hierarchical data in MySQL](http://mikehillyer.com/articles/managing-hierarchical-data-in-mysql/). Using this model, queries to do simple things like in your question are simple too.
With this model, your table structure would be this following:

```
comment_id int(11) No auto_increment
article_id int(11)
lft int NOT NULL
rgt int NOT NULL
profile_id int(11) No
text mediumtext No
datetime datetime No
vote_score int(11)
```

your example data would look like this

```
comment_id article_id lft rgt profile_id text              datetime vote_score
------------------------------------------------------------------------------
     1         1       1   6      ?      comment 1            ?        ****
     2         1       2   3      ?      reply to comment1    ?         **
     3         1       4   5      ?      reply to comment2    ?        ****
     4         2       1   2      ?      comment2             ?         *
```

Now with this model, getting the comments in the right order is really easy :

```
ORDER BY article_id, lft
```

Switching to this model will spare you a lot of recursion headaches I think. Have fun!

P.S: Are you swedish? O:-)

Answer (score 0):

One way to do this:

```
SELECT pr.name_f,c1.comment_id AS comment_1, c1.profile_id AS profile_id_1, c1.type AS type_1, c1.parent_id AS parent_id_1, c1.text AS text_1, c1.datetime AS datetime_1, c1.vote_score AS score_1, c2.comment_id AS comment_2, c2.profile_id AS profile_id_2, c2.type AS type_2, c2.parent_id AS parent_id_2, c2.text AS text_2, c2.datetime AS datetime_2, c2.vote_score AS score_2 FROM profiles AS pr, comments AS c1 

LEFT JOIN mcomments AS c2 ON c2.parent_id=c1.comment_id AND c2.comment_idc1.comment_id 

WHERE c1.article_id = '1' AND (pr.profile_id=c1.profile_id OR pr.profile_id=c2.profile_id)
```

Then simple PHP arrays of comment_id's can prevent duplicate/sub comments from being posted.

I'm sure there's a better way?